# Django application error when deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I want to deploy my Python / Django application on Heroku but I'm caught up with this weird error. One of the errors I couldn't fix was

```
wrapt==1.12.1) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)
```

I have searched everywhere on the internet and `pip` installing `wrapt==1.12.1` but still, I kept getting the same error. What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

The full error message is below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

You are only quoting part of the error message. Here's a more complete quote:

```
Requested runtime (appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.7
...
wrapt==1.12.1) is not available for this stack (heroku-18
```

This indicates a problem with your *`runtime.txt` file*. That file isn't for defining your dependencies; it's for telling Heroku what version of Python you want to use. It [should only contain something like](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime)

```
python-3.8.5
```

Dependencies go into a file called `requirements.txt` (or, if you're using Pipenv, `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, but that doesn't seem to apply here).

I suspect simply renaming your `runtime.txt` to `requirements.txt`, committing the change, and redeploying will work. If you want to specify a particular Python version, you should also create a new `runtime.txt` in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

After installing **wrapt==1.12.1** follow this steps:

Write below command in your reminal:

```
  pip freeze > requirements.txt
    
    git add .
    git commit -m "edit"
    git push heroku master
```