# Getting "Requested runtime is not available for this stack (heroku-20)." error with correct versions of Python

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, runtime

The main issue that I could not find anywhere else is that the bracket contains all the other lines of runtime.txt. which makes me believe something else is wrong but I can't find any solution online. Buildlog attached for reference.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Requested runtime (asgiref==3.4.1
colorama==0.4.4
comtypes==1.1.10
cycler==0.10.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.6
docx2pdf==0.1.7
gunicorn==20.1.0
joblib==1.0.1
kiwisolver==1.3.2
lxml==4.6.3
matplotlib==3.4.3
mysql-connector-python==8.0.26
numpy==1.21.2
Pillow==8.3.2
psycopg2==2.9.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-docx==0.8.11
pytz==2021.1
pywin32==227
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.7.1
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
threadpoolctl==2.2.0
tqdm==4.62.3
whitenoise==5.3.0
python-3.9.7) is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: This is a dupe of [Django application error when deploying to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63966719/354577) but unfortunately I can't close as a dupe since no answers there are upvoted or accepted. OP over there commented that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63968511/354577) solve their problem but neglected to accept it. Basically, your `runtime.txt` should contain _only_ `python-3.9.7`. All your other dependencies go into `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue and the problem turned out to be the line `pywin32==227`. Apparently I coded everything in windows and heroku is on linux and hence it did not word, I just deleted the pywin32 line and it works now.